# async not waiting for await in callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, polymer-2.0

I have a function that has to be async because I need it to sleep at some point for half a second, but then I'd just like it to be completely sequential. I'm doing the following:

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

checkNearestStreetView(panoData){
  if(panoData){
    if(panoData.location){
      if(panoData.location.latLng){
        console.log("new panodata" + panoData.location.latLng);
        this.currentpos = panoData.location.latLng;
        console.log("new panodata:" + this.currentpos);
      }
    }
  } else {
    this.currentpos = null;
    console.log("no new panodata");
  }
}    

async updateLocation(feature, layer) {
      console.log("Oh");
      await sleep(500);
      console.log("Hi");
      console.log("Mark!");

      var webService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();  
      var checkaround = 50;

      ...

      console.log("curentpos before checknearest " + this.currentpos);
      await webService.getPanoramaByLocation(this.currentpos, checkaround, await this.checkNearestStreetView.bind(this));
      console.log("curentpos after checknearest " + this.currentpos);      
    console.log("success");
  }
```

I would like `checkNearestStreetView` to run completely before the code continues to run, so I'm trying to `await` it and only continue once it's done. But with the above code, `checkNearestStreetView` runs in async, and I get the following output on the console:

```
Oh
Hi
Mark! 
curentpos before checknearest (42.59678542, -76.15251434999999) 
curentpos after checknearest (42.59678542, -76.15251434999999)
success
no new panodata
```

Meaning `checkNearestStreetView` only finishes running *after* everything else ran, even though I told the function to `await` it (and `getPanoramaByLocation`). There might be something I'm misunderstanding on the subject of `await`, please help me learn why this happens this way!

Comment: here - `await this.checkNearestStreetView.bind(this)` you are not calling the function, you are creating a new one with binded context

Either call the function and pass an argument or use `await` inside `getPanoramaByLocation` (I don't know what the function do and what it expects)

Comment: `getPanoramaByLocation` is a Google webservice: http://branflake2267.github.io/GWT-Maps-V3-Api/javadoc/3.8.1/com/google/gwt/maps/client/streetview/StreetViewService.html#getPanoramaByLocation(com.google.gwt.maps.client.base.LatLng,%20double,%20com.google.gwt.maps.client.streetview.PanoramaByLocationHandler) 

I need to bind `.this` to the function as I intend to use some of the context variables within `checkNearestStreetView`. Could you please show me what you mean with code? Not sure I understand all the concepts yet.

Comment: I don't know what do you want to do, but, I'm certain, you don't have to `await` result of `bind` function as it returns a new function and doesn't call original one.

Probably you want to await the function the `bind` returns?

You gave me a link to some Java library and I don't know what I have to see there.

Comment: You asked what `getPanoramaByLocation` is, I sent you the documentation for it. Yes, I want to await the function `checkNearestStreetView` with the context bound to it. How do I do that?

Comment: you have to call it...

Comment: AFAIK I *am* calling it via callback. Could you please demonstrate via code?

Comment: It gets called, I get the output on the console. It's just not called in the right order.